# ¿Porque sucede esto? No entiendo. (.addEventListener('click',... se ejecuta automáticamente sin dar click en nada)

Tags: javascript, html

Antes que nada cabe aclarar que soy nuevo en el tema de la programación y claramente en JavaScript. Literalmente nuevo, llevo en esto 1 semana...

Al poner la función (quoteService) que se ejecutara a dar click, así:

```
document.querySelector("#wb_element_instance43 > a.wb_button").addEventListener('click', quoteService);
```

**Funciona perfectamente**, la funcion "*quoteService*" se ejecuta al dar click sobre "*#wb_element_instance43 > a.wb_button*". **¡Bien!**

**Pero**, al querer ponerlo así ( quoteService() ) para usar un parámetro:

```
document.querySelector("#wb_element_instance43 > a.wb_button").addEventListener('click', quoteService());
```

Ejecuta la función "*quoteService*" automáticamente al cargar la linea... Por decir cuando carga el archivo .js, osea no solo define que "al clickear en dicho botón, ejecute dicha función" sin que directamente, ejecuta dicha función, como si toda la linea se remplazara por un simple "quoteService();"...

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con cargar la linea?

Comment: Por decir cuando carga el archivo .js, osea no solo define que "al clickear en dicho botón, ejecute dicha función" sin que directamente, ejecuta dicha función, como si toda la linea se remplazara por un simple "quoteService();"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript al leer el código, debe recoger la referencia o nombre de la función a la que llamar cuando se ejecute el query selector. Si indicas que la función a llamar es "quoteService()" directamente esta ejecutando la función en el momento de la lectura del código.

Puedes ver un ejemplo en W3schools como se hacen las llamadas a una función en un eventlistener de javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp
En la documentación que te he insertado tienes los parámetros disponibles para este evento. Puedes recuperar datos del evento o bien recuperar los parámetros que quieras del DOM dentro de la función.

Para pasar parámetros puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
function quoteService(event){
    console.log(event);
    var example = document.getElementById("elementId");
    console.log(example);
}

document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener('click', quoteService);


document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener('click', function(event){
    //Recuperar parámetros.
    console.log(event);
    var example = document.getElementById("elementId");
    console.log(example);
});
```

Comment: Perfecto amigo, gracias. +1.
Saque de tu código lo que me pareció conveniente para mi codigo y al final lo use así: (y anduvo perfecto 10/10)
`document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener('click', function(event){/**/});`
Y entendí porque fallaba, y ya encontre el ejemplo de este code en w3school. ¡Very thanks good men!